# Uploading zip files via http occasionally results in a corrupt file (failed CRC check)

Tags: c#, windows, http, file-upload, zip

I have run into a very odd problem.  When uploading a zip file from a Windows 8 client (written in C#) to an IIS webpage (also in C#) running on Server 2008 R2, the file occasionally gets corrupted.  We have not been able to reproduce the issue with any other client OS (Windows 7, Vista, XP).  It is not consistent, but occurs often enough to be an issue.

When I examined the zip file using a binary diff tool, I found that the replacements were in a definite pattern.

[Binary diff comparison](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjfmqddyhbkya9c/binarycompare.png)

This is an example of the replacements.  The pattern is consistent between different instances of the files.  The top is the original file, the bottom is the uploaded file saved on the server side.

The pattern of all of the changes is the same.  First an eight byte block of the pattern:

> 0 0 C 0 F r e e

where `C` is some character, followed by an eight byte unmodified section.

Then there is a 16 byte modified section divided into two identical 8 byte blocks.

The pattern is too consistent to be random, but I have no idea what is causing the problems.  I am not even sure where to start.

The code has been running on Windows 7 and XP for years with no obvious problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a network card driver issue in vmware.  Once we updated our vmware version everything went back to being happy.

Answer (score 0):

The only guess is that something happens on the transport level. The way to diagnose the problem: upload the same file using different client / code / component and see if the issue goes away. The actual changes in the file are most likely irrelevant. I think that either chunked encoding or compression (or both) is used for transfer and it breaks the data due to the error in the client or in the server. Another component will address this if you can ensure that no chunked encoding and no compression are employed.

Comment: I am unfortunately beginning to agree the problem is in the transport layer (which is very very bad).  I'm not sure if I agree that the modifications are not significant.  They follow an absolute pattern (the example is just that, one out of many).  The use of the English word "Free" is key here I think.  Somewhere someone put that literal string in so that they could come back and find it later.

Comment: @athelred could as well be a consequence of memory corruption. Try using another client.